# How do I Nest Two Loops in one do while?

Tags: excel, loops, do-while, vba

I'm trying to nest two loops in a do while.

Basically while there is a valid Email, I want to check if I should be sending an email (Y/N), if no -> Loop, if Y, Here is the email, then Loop. I have already DIM'd everything correctly

Please see code below. Thank you.

```
Sub EmailDisplay()
Do While Email <> vbNullString 
    If Sheets("Mail").Cells(Count, 1).Value = N Then
    Count = Count + 1
    Loop

    If Sheets("Mail").Cells(Count, 1).Value = Y Then
    Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0) 
    Name = Sheets("Mail").Cells(Count, 2).Value


Count = Count + 1 'Updates Variable count to continue loop
Email = Sheets("Mailing").Cells(Count, 1).Value 

End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Right now I see Compile error - Loop Without Do for the first Loop.

Comment: Well you have a two if statements and only one end if. Your Do While is only looping after the count. The error is because your final loop isn't attached to anything.

Comment: Thank you BerticusMaximus - if I put the Red stop code thing at If Sheets = Y line, I get the Compile Error of Loop Without Do. However, they can clearly see there is a Do While there.

I've also tried adding in a second do while Email <> vbNullstring, but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Visual Basic but try this:

```
Sub EmailDisplay()
'I added next two line because Count and Email are not initialized
Count = 1
Email = Sheets("Mailing").Cells(Count, 1).Value 
Do While Email <> vbNullString 
    If Sheets("Mail").Cells(Count, 1).Value = Y Then
        Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0) 
        Name = Sheets("Mail").Cells(Count, 2).Value
    End If
    Count = Count + 1 'Updates Variable count to continue loop
    Email = Sheets("Mailing").Cells(Count, 1).Value 
Loop
End Sub
```

I don't think you need nested loops here. Here we have one loop with an if block for your two cases. BTW. If you need nested loops you need to make sure that every "Do While" has one and only one matching "Loop"

Comment: thank you for this Dabisa Kelava - I will try it and report back. thank you so much.

Comment: It doesn't work - For example, if Count = 1 is N, then I want it to go to Count = 2 and test if that is also N. I think the nested loop is necessary - I don't want it to go from Count = 1 = N to Count = 2 and proceed to email if Count = 2 is also N. What do you think?

Comment: I changed the code in proposed solution so you can try again. But I must say that I don't really understand what are you trying to achieve. The problem might be that variables Count and Email are not initialized, so I added initialization of those variables.